# How do I update a module manually?

Tags: updating

I need to update my Views module in Drupal 7. Drupal won't do it automatically. It says the download is not available.

I have downloaded the new version manually, but when I try to install it via 'add new module', the message is 'views is already installed'. How do I update the module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updating a module is usually two steps:

1. Replace the files with the new version you downloaded, for example via FTP.
2. Run update.php (it is not always needed, but run it to check if updates are needed).

When updating, it can be a good idea to try the update on a local development environment to check that nothing breaks, and do a backup before the live update. Some updates are minor and won't need this.

Views, which stores a lot of configuration in the database and has recently undergone major changes, is one of those modules where you usually want to test it out before upgrading.

Comment: Also, especially on big updates like the recent Views update, it is important to remove all old files before uploading the new files. If a file is renamed and you just upload the new module, you will end up with both files. This can cause problems, for example fatal errors when two functions of the same name are included.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find everything you need from at the following links:

- [Update Modules Best Practice](http://groups.drupal.org/node/19513)
- [How to Update Drupal Modules](http://www.ehow.com/how_7387345_update-drupal-modules.html)

IMO, the most important step is: don't forget to always backup your database before any changes.